# How to implement a client to client message passing through server(chatting)?

Tags: java, client-server, chat

My task is to built a client to client chatting program through server. client A will send a message to server which then forwards to client B and vice a versa. all this shall happen live simultaneously till one of them closes it. I have the following program.

Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class chatServer {

public static Socket s1 = new Socket();
public static Socket s2 = new Socket();
private final static int port1 = 5561;
private final static int port2 = 5562;  

public static void main(String[] args) {    


    try{
        ServerSocket se = new ServerSocket(port1);
        ServerSocket sa = new ServerSocket(port2);
        s1 = se.accept();
        s2 = sa.accept();
    }catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
    System.out.println("##");
    chatServer c = new chatServer();
    chatServer.handler1 h1 = c.new handler1();
    chatServer.handler2 h2 = c.new handler2();

    h1.start();
    h2.start();
}   

public class handler1 extends Thread {

    public void run() {


            try{
                InputStream in = s1.getInputStream();
                System.out.println(s1.isConnected());
                BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));        
                PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(s2.getOutputStream(),true);  
                while(true) {   
                    if(buff!=null) {
                        System.out.println(buff.readLine().toString());
                        pout.println(buff.readLine().toString());
                    }
                }           
            }catch(IOException i){
                System.out.println(i);
            }

    }
}

public class handler2 extends Thread {

    public void run() {

            try{
                InputStream in = s2.getInputStream();
                System.out.println(s2.isConnected());
                BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));        
                PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream(),true);
                while(true) {
                    if(buff!=null) {                    
                        pout.println(buff.readLine().toString());
                        System.out.println(buff.readLine().toString());
                    }
                }
            }catch(IOException i) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }

    }
  }
}
```

Client 1:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;



public class client1 {

private final static String IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
private final static int port = 5561;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Socket s = new Socket(IPAddress,port);      
        client2 c = new client2();
        client2.listener l = c.new listener(s);
        client2.publisher p = c.new publisher(s);
        l.start();
        p.start();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}

public class listener extends Thread {

    Socket s1 = new Socket();
    listener(Socket c){
        s1=c;
    }
    public void run() {
    try{    
    InputStream in = s1.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader b =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        while(true) {

                    String l = b.readLine();
                    if(l!=null)                 
                        System.out.println(l);

            }
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println(ioe);
            }

    }   
}   

public class publisher extends Thread {

    Socket s2 = new Socket();
    publisher(Socket c){
        s2=c;
    }
    public void run() {
    try {   
        InputStream in = s2.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader b =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));         
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s2.getOutputStream(),true);
        while(true) {

                    String str = b.readLine();
                    if(str!=null)   
                        out.println(str);

            }
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println(ioe);
            }   
    }   
 }  
}
```

Client 2:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.net.*;



public class client2 {

private final static String IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
private final static int port = 5562;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        Socket s = new Socket(IPAddress,port);      
        client2 c = new client2();
        client2.listener l = c.new listener(s);
        client2.publisher p = c.new publisher(s);
        l.start();
        p.start();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}

public class listener extends Thread {

    Socket s1 = new Socket();
    listener(Socket c){
        s1=c;
    }
    public void run() {
    try{

            InputStream in = s1.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader b =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream(),true);
        while(true) {
                    String l = b.readLine();
                    if(l!=null)
                        out.println(l);
            }

        }catch(IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println(ioe);
            }
    }   
}   

public class publisher extends Thread {
    Socket s1 = new Socket();
    publisher(Socket c){
        s1=c;
    }
    public void run() {

    try {

            InputStream in = s1.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader b =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));                
            BufferedReader b2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while(true) {

                    String st = b2.readLine();
                    if(st!=null )
                        System.out.println(st);
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println(ioe);
            }   
    }   
 }  
}
```

The above codes are running without any compiler error. But the are not passing messages. Messages passed are displayed on the respective client terminals. Connection is ok. But the communication is not happening. Please guide me through this.

Comment: each of them just reading socket but there is no writer on them... check this link fo rexample https://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/socket.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you invoke `buff.readLine()`, you actually *consume* a line from the stream. The next time you call it, you will read a new line if there is one, otherwise the call may block if the underlying stream blocks.

See the javaDocs of [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--).

Therefore, as you call `readLine` twice in your loops, you will only see any output if your clients send at least two lines, and the line forwarded to the other client will be the first one, while the second one will be printed to `System.out`.